# Form validation with NgModel angular 7

Tags: angular, forms, validation, ngmodel

I don't know how my Ngclass not working, if you found the solution thank you soo much

In my HTML :

```
<form [formGroup]="pageForm">
 ... 
 <input [(ngModel)]="namePage" type="text" class="form-control">
 ... 

<div class="d-flex mt-4">
  <i [ngClass]="{ 'is-valid': !f.name.errors }"></i>
</div>

</form>
```

In my TS:

```
pageForm: FormGroup;
namePage: string;

// the form
this.pageForm = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl([this.namePage, Validators.required]),
 });

get f() {
 return this.pageForm.controls;
}
```

Comment: if you use ReactiveForm (formGroup) NOT use [ngModel], the correct sintax is `<input formControlName="name">`

Comment: @Eliseo Thank you, but I need my ngmodel cause this name have to be change in another place in real time

Comment: @Juan Oh escuse me. It's ngclass not ngstyle. My fault

Comment: you can always write {{pageForm.get('namePage').value}}, or use a getter. When you use [(ngModel)] into a Reactive form is to manage a variable NOT in the form, and you need use [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
isValid: boolean = false;

get f() {
 this.isValid = this.pageForm.valid;
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="pageForm"  (ngSubmit)="f()">
 ... 
 <input [(ngModel)]="namePage" type="text" class="form-control">
 ... 

<div class="d-flex mt-4">
  <i [ngClass]="{ 'is-valid': isValid }"></i>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Create a variable. Do not call the function.

Comment: Call to get f when submitting the form.